# SharePoint Designer Workflow - Add a person to a person or group field from an initiation form

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer, person

I have a custom list. On the custom list there is a person or group field that allows for multiple selections.

I am trying to create a workflow which has an initiation form.

The initiation form has a person or group field that is just a single item selection.

The goal of this workflow is to basically be the same thing as if some one were to edit the person or group field directly on the form and add the person there.

So far what I have tried is creating a variable called "new_dl" to be set as

`[%Current Item:Distribution List%]#;[%Paramater: Person to add%]`

Then I have an action to update the the current item new_dl; however, it does not work. If I log new_dl it shows:

```
187;#Jane Doe#;<pcPerson xmllns:pc=.....
```

basically telling me that the parameter string coming from the Initiation form has that XML stuff that can't be used in the standard update list item action.

A couple of things that I have tried:

On the `[Current Item:Distribution List%]` I had it return just the login ID's semicolon deliminated as well as the `[%Paramater: Person to add%]` return just the login ID's semicolon deliminated and I get the log that I would expect `187#;23` however trying to use that to update the list item with doesn't seem to be working. oddly enough I don't get an error when doing that; however, the effect that I want does not happen.

Basically somehow I need to concatenate the current value, with the value given from the initiation form to update the field with a new correct value.

SharePoint 2013. This list workflow was created using the SharePoint 2010 Workflow Platform Type.